# Fit the text to the textview (with height = "fill_parent") by editting the xml file

Tags: android, xml, text, textview

I have a textview which is defined in my xml file. I want to make the text in the textview to fit the textview. I have set the height of the textview to "fill_parent"(I cannot use "wrap_content" because I want to keep the textview to fit in its parent layout). Also I want to align the text to the right side of the textview(I used the gravity property for this, but dosen't work.). What lines of code should I add to the xml file for fitting the text and aligning the text.

Comment: Have you tried android:layout-weight=0

Comment: @jjpp - Please accept or vote up the answer if it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Add this for right alignment

```
android:gravity="right"
android:textAlignment="gravity"
```

As for filling the entire screen, there is no such command as far as I know and have searched. You could make your own function for it though. Keep increasing the text programmatically and set up a scroll view and see if the scroll bar has come into view, once it does, set the text size to a value lesser than the one which calls the scrollbar.

It seems flawed, but it works.